# ¿Cómo dar un tiempo de eliminación individual a los ítems?

Tags: javascript, html5

```js
document.querySelector(".datos-nota").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".divGenerated").forEach((element)=>{
        let hijoDiv = element.querySelector(".chek");
        let time = setTimeout(()=>{
                if(hijoDiv.checked){
                element.remove();
                
                }
            },1000);
        })});
         document.querySelector(".boton-icono").addEventListener("click",()=>{
            document.querySelectorAll(".divGenerated").forEach((e)=>{
                e.remove();
            })
         });
        document.addEventListener('keyup',(e)=>{
            if(e.keyCode === 13){
                addHomeWork();
            }
        });
            function addHomeWork(){
            let lista = document.querySelector(".datos-nota");
            let input = document.querySelector(".input-user");
            
            if(input.value == ""){
                return Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Parece que no has escrito nada!',
                });
                 }
            let newDiv = `<div class="divGenerated">
                        <label class="lab">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="chek">
                        <span></span>
                        ${input.value}
                        </label>
                         </div>`;
            lista.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",newDiv);
            input.value = "";
                };
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="main-datos-info">

            <div class="datos-info">
                <div class="datos-info-items">
                    <h4>Agrega una tarea!</h4>
                    <input class="input-user" type="text" maxlength="40" required>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="add" onclick="addHomeWork()">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button title="Borrar todo" class="boton-icono">
            Borrar todo
        </button>
        <div class="main-datos-nota">
            <div class="titular">Vamos a completar estas tareas!</div>
            <div class="datos-nota" >
                <!-- <div class="titular">!Vamos a completar estas tareas!</div> -->
                <div class="divGenerated">
                    <label class="lab">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="chek">
                        <span></span>
                        soy una tarea sin completar :C
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

El contexto es el siguiente: tengo este programa de lista de tareas donde el usuario puede eliminar las tareas agregadas por medio del checkbox; cuando se activa el check de una tarea hice que se eliminara con un setTimeoUt después de 1 segundo para darle chance al usuario de deshacer el check si él desea. El problema es que cuando el usuario selecciona varias tareas rápidamente todos los checkbox marcados se eliminan en el transcurso de ese segundo en general y no 1 segundo individual. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer que se elimine cada uno con 1 segundo individualmente? ¿O de qué forma me recomendarían hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando la posición del setTimeout, algo así:

```
document.querySelector(".datos-nota").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".divGenerated").forEach((element)=>{
        let hijoDiv = element.querySelector(".chek");
        if(hijoDiv.checked){
          let time = setTimeout(()=>{
                
                element.remove();
                
                
            },3000)};
        })})
```

Así el setTimeout inicia al darle check.

Otra cosa, podrías cambiar el keyCode, está deprecado, en su lugar prueba con:

```
e.key === 'Enter'
```

Comment: si bro, así lo tenia antes pero si te fijas cuando lo marcas y lo desmarcas se elimina igualmente, por eso puse el if dentro para dar la posibilidad de cancelar la eliminación. Lo que quiero es que cada uno tenga su tiempo de eliminacion individual y con la posibilidad de cancelar el check

Comment: ah y gracias por el tip del keyCode no me la sabia jsjs

Comment: Acabo de probar esto, poner el if fuera y dentro del setTime out, hace una doble comprobacion y permite anular
`
if(hijoDiv.checked){
          let time = setTimeout(()=>{
            if(hijoDiv.checked){
                
                element.remove();
            }
                
            },3000)};
        })}e esta `
recien arranco en stack, no se como poner formato codigo en comentarios, ja

Answer (score 0):

```
var notascontainer = document.querySelector(".datos-nota") // seleccion del contenedor de notas
            
function addHomeWork(){
  let lista = document.querySelector(".datos-nota");
  let input = document.querySelector(".input-user");
              
    if(input.value == ""){
       return Swal.fire({
       icon: 'error',
       title: 'Oops...',
       text: 'Parece que no has escrito nada!',
         });
                   }
       let newDiv = `<div class="divGenerated">
                     <label class="lab">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="chek">
                     <span></span>
                     ${input.value}
                     </label>
                     </div>`;
       lista.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",newDiv);
       input.value = "";
            
              notascontainer.firstChild.querySelector(".chek").addEventListener("change",(e) => {
                 // aprovecho que agregas el elemento al principio para usar la propiedad firstChild del contenedor 
                 // y seleccionar el div que se crea en esta funcion y le agrego un evento change
                if(e.target.checked) setTimeout(() => notascontainer.removeChild(e.target.parentNode.parentNode),1000)
                 // si el target del evento cambia, y si cambia a true (es checked) al pasar 1 segundo se elimina dicho nodo. Los timeouts son independientes y desaparecen segun el orden de clickeo. el doble parentNode es para seleccionar el divContenedor de ese inputcheck y asi poder eliminarlo.
              })
            };
```

Basicamente agrego los eventos en el momento en el que creo la tarea, cada una con su timeout correspondiente por lo que no interfieren entre si, y no tengo necesidad de hacer bucles.

Comment: Probé tu código bro y si funciona pero igual, la diferencia es que cuando tu marcas y desmarcas el check el elemento se elimina igual, por eso puse un condicional dentro del setTimeOut por si se desmarca el check que no se elimine, si te fijas bien todos los checks también tienen su tiempo individual, el problema es que cuando tu marcas un check y lo desmarcas el segundo sigue corriendo y si marcas en seguida otro check se eliminara con el tiempo del anterior y no del suyo.